# I'm trying to turn a data frame into a sql in python, but I'm aways getting this output: sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite, tmp

I've looked for similar topics on stack overflow and google, but I couldn't find any similar case. Can anyone help me?

```
import os
import tempfile
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

tmp = tempfile.mktemp()
try:
        tmpDb = sqlite3.connect(tmp)
finally:
        try:
            if os.path.exists(tmp):
                os.remove(tmp)
        finally:
            tmpDb.commit()
accessions= ["WP_010881498.1", "WP_010881746.1", "WP_010881771.1"]
accessions_df = pd.DataFrame(accessions, columns= ['accessions'])
accessions_df.to_sql(name = "query", con = tmpDb, if_exists = 'replace')
```

Comment: You remove the file you have just to create, so yes there is an I/O Error because the file do not exist anymore :) Why do you create a temporary database? In this case, use `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` to create a database in memory.

Comment: It was my first time using a temporary file. Sorry for the stupid mistake and thank you very much for your help @Corralien!!!!!